# Selecting zero or more objects from $n$ identical objects

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I just read in a book that the number of ways of selecting zero or more objects from $n$ identical objects is $n+1$. Could you please explain how is that derived? Thanks is advance!

Comment: Normally one should also include where they got stuck or felt a great deal of difficulty. This helps you by allowing us to give you the best answer :)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to indicate that you meant identical objects.  Otherwise, people will derive the formula for the number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements.  You can find that derivation by searching the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original question (which had "different" rather than "identical") is incorrect.  The number of ways of selecting zero or more objects from $n$ *identical* objects is $n+1$, as follows: $$0, 1,2, \ldots, n$$
There are $n+1$ numbers in the above list.

Comment: Thank you ! I actually mean identical .. just a slip of hand .. thanks anyways !